# Not able to set/update/add response header( parameter - "Server") in Bottle Paste server

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to explicitly update a response header, specifically `Server = NULL`.

```
response.set_header('Server', ' ')
response.add_header('Server', ' ')
```

I am running server with Paste as:

```
app.run(host='localhost', port=5010, debug=True, server='paste')
```

However, I am not able to make changes for parameter `Server`. Default response I am getting is " `server →PasteWSGIServer/0.5 Python/2.7.13` "

I am able to change other parameters like `Content_Type` but when I am running server without Paste as :

```
app.run(host='localhost', port=5010, debug=True)
```

I am able to make changes to all parameters.

Please suggest what is the problem and if possible what would be the resolution for this?

Comment: any solution on this please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bottle import ServerAdapter
class PasteServer(ServerAdapter):
    def run(self, handler): # pragma: no cover
        from paste import httpserver
        from paste.translogger import TransLogger
        handler = TransLogger(handler, setup_console_handler=(not self.quiet))
        httpserver.serve(handler, host=self.host, port=str(self.port), server_version=" ", **self.options)
paste_server = PasteServer(host="<ip>", port="<port>")
run(server=paste_server)
```

`server_version=" "` This parameter value overrides the server response's "Server" header value. Go through paste's **httpserver.py** for more details.

server_version -> class WSGIHandler class WSGIHandlerMixin --> version_string --> function serve --> function for parameter details

Comment: server_version=" " # this parameter value overrides the server response's "Server" header value  
Go through paste's httpserver.py for more details    
server_version -> class WSGIHandler  
class WSGIHandlerMixin --> version_string --> function  
serve -->  function for parameter details